# PHP sockets and streams, client data is unreadable in server-side after handshake

Tags: javascript, php, sockets, websocket

I'm trying to make simple sockets application with php. Okay so the principle is to handle n amount of chat rooms and multiple functions inside these rooms which involve client-to-client communication through sockets. So here's what I have so far:

1. Client connects, handshake with headers goes through ok
2. Sockets script stores clients in array, handles new connections and disconnections, keeps track of which client has which rooms(n:n) etc
3. Client side I'm using my own syntax how to control the sockets server for example join a room -> "delimiteraction:joindelimiterid:2delimiter", but the problem rises here. I can't get any human readable data from the socket after the handshake. I'm using putty to monitor the socket script and it shows mostly white bars where the data should be also the data seems to be different each time(same client message but different socket data), but length is mostly same(not a non-blocking issue already tried blocking)

I've tried to decode, encode, binary conversions, tried using both streams and sockets but nothing seems to work.

I'm new to sockets, but not to php.
Here's client code:

```
var delimiter = "maybeencodesomeofit";
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://myip:myport');
connection.onopen = function(e){//define handshake
    alert("connection established");

    var message = delimiter+"action:join"+delimiter+"userid:1"+"EOD_MARK";
    connection.send("somegood10lobbyid:1somegood10body:"+message+"\r");
}

connection.onerror = function (error){
    alert("connection errored");
    console.log(error);
}

connection.onmessage = function(e){
    alert("connection message");
}
connection.onclose = function(e){
    alert("closed connection");
}
```

Here's server code:

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);

// create a streaming socket, of type TCP/IP
$sock = stream_socket_server("tcp://myip:myport", $errno, $errstr);
stream_set_blocking($sock,TRUE);
// start listen for connections
// create a list of all the clients that will be connected to us..
// add the listening socket to this list
$clients = array($sock);
$incomplete_data = array();
$end_of_data = "EOD_MARK";
$clients_lobbies = array();
$received_header = array();
$handshakes = array();
echo phpversion();
//define all the lobbies to direct messages to,
$lobbies = array();
echo "Sockets initialized";
while (true) {
    // create a copy, so $clients doesn't get modified by socket_select()
    $read = $clients;
    foreach($received_header as $key => $header){
        if($header['time']+1 < microtime(true)){
            $headers  = [];
            echo $header['data'];
            $lines    = preg_split("/\r\n/", $header['data']);
            foreach($lines as $line) {
                $line = chop($line);
                if(preg_match('/\A(\S+): (.*)\z/', $line, $matches)){
                    $headers[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
                }
            }
            $secKey     = $headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'];
            $secAccept  = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($secKey . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));

            // create handshake header
            $upgrade  = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
            "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
            "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
            "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: $secAccept\r\n\r\n";

            // send handshake packet
            fwrite($clients[$key], $upgrade);
            $handshakes[$key] = true;
            $unset_key = $key;
        }
    }
    if(isset($unset_key)){
        unset($received_header[$key]);
        unset($unset_key);
    }

    //check incomplete data and delete the data after 5 seconds
    $unset_keys = array();
    foreach($incomplete_data as $key => $array){
        if($array['last_update']+5 < microtime(true)){
            $unset_keys[$key] = true;
        }
    }
    foreach($unset_keys as $key => $arr){
        unset($incomplete_data[$key]);
    }
    unset($unset_keys);


    // get a list of all the clients that have data to be read from
    // if there are no clients with data, go to next iteration
    if (stream_select($read, $write = NULL, $except = NULL, 0) === FALSE)
        continue;

    // check if there is a client trying to connect
    if (in_array($sock, $read)) {
        // accept the client, and add him to the $clients array
        $clients[] = $newsock = stream_socket_accept($sock);
        $key = array_search($sock, $read);
        // remove the listening socket from the clients-with-data array

        unset($read[$key]);
    }

    // loop through all the clients that have data to read from
    foreach ($read as $read_sock) {
        // read until newline or 1024 bytes
        $key = array_search($read_sock, $clients);
        //echo "Data incoming";
        // socket_read while show errors when the client is disconnected, so silence the error messages
        $data = fread($read_sock, 4096);
        //get the headers for the first handshake
        if(!isset($handshakes[$key])){
            //we need to handshake it first before we continue with normal operation
            $received_header[$key]['data'] .= $data;
            $received_header[$key]['time'] = microtime(true);
            continue;
        }
        // check if the client is disconnected
        if ($data === false) {
            echo "Client disconnected";
            // remove client from $clients array
            $key = array_search($read_sock, $clients);
            fclose($read_sock);
            unset($clients[$key]);
            //remove client from lobbies 
            if(isset($clients_lobbies[$key])){
                foreach($clients_lobbies[$key] as $lobbyid => $boolean){
                    unset($lobbies[$lobbyid]['clients'][$key]);
                }
            }
            unset($received_header[$key]);
            unset($handshakes[$key]);
            //remove clients indexed lobbies
            unset($clients_lobbies[$key]);
            unset($incomplete_data[$key]);
            // continue to the next client to read from, if any
            continue;
        }

        // trim off the trailing/beginning white spaces
        //$data = trim($data);

        // check if there is any data after trimming off the spaces
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $parsing_data = array();

            echo $data;
            //PARSE DATA HERE, Direct the messages into the lobbies according to headers, headers will tell if the user wants to join another lobby, what lobby the message is from etc,
            if($key !== false && isset($handshakes[$key])){
                if(isset($incomplete_data[$key])){
                    echo "incomplete data";
                    $data = $incomplete_data[$key]['data'].$data;
                    $incomplete_data[$key]['data'] = $data;
                    $incomplete_data[$key]['last_update'] = microtime(true);
                }else{
                    $incomplete_data[$key]['data'] = $data;
                    $incomplete_data[$key]['last_update'] = microtime(true);
                }
                if(substr_compare($data,$end_of_data,-strlen($end_of_data) !== 0)){//check if data has arrived completely
                    $incomplete_data[$key]['data'] = $data;
                    $incomplete_data[$key]['last_update'] = microtime(true);
                    continue;
                }else{
                    echo "Data is here.".$data;
                    //whole data is here
                    unset($incomplete_data[$key]);
                    $delimiter = substr($data,0,10);//get first 10 characters as delimiter;
                    $parsing_data = explode($delimiter,$data);
                    if(count($parsing_data) === 1){//something went wrong and there's no headers

                    }
                    //we can start doing magic here
                    $headers = array();
                    $body = "";
                    foreach($parsing_data as $header){ //parse headers last one will be with key "body" and contains the message to be written to participant sockets
                        $element = explode(":",$header);
                        if(count($element) === 2 && $element[0] !== 'body'){
                            $headers[strval($element[0])] = strval($element[1]);
                        }elseif($element[0] === 'body'){
                            $body = strval($element[1]);
                        }
                    }
                    if(isset($headers['lobbyid'])){//there's defined lobbyid to send message to
                        //forward the message
                        if(!isset($lobbies[$headers['lobbyid']])){
                            //create the lobby
                            $lobbies[$headers['lobbyid']] = array();
                            //join the lobby
                            $lobbies[$headers['lobbyid']]['clients'][$key] = $read_sock;
                        }
                        $clients_lobbies[$key][$headers['lobbyid']] = true;
                        // lobby exists -> forward the message to all, including the sender
                        foreach($lobbies[$headers['lobbyid']]['clients'] as $client_keys => $receivers){
                            if(isset($clients[$client_keys])){
                                fwrite($clients[$client_keys], $body);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } // end of reading foreach
}

// close the listening socket
socket_close($sock);
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, you need to unmask the client-to-server data then re-encode, the unmask function needs to be able to handle multiple frames(nagle's algorithm). Code below will unmask multiple frames accordingly
Here's the code:

```
function unmask($payload){  
    $decMessages = Array(); 
    do { // This should be running until all frames are unmasked and added to 
        $decMessages Array 
        $length = ord($payload[1]) & 127;
        if($length == 126) {
            $payload_len = 8;
            $masks = substr($payload, 4, 4);
            $data = substr($payload, 8);
            $len = (ord($payload[2]) << 8) + ord($payload[3]);
        }elseif($length == 127) {
            $payload_len = 14;
            $masks = substr($payload, 10, 4);
            $data = substr($payload, 14);
            $len = (ord($payload[2]) << 56) + (ord($payload[3]) << 48) +
                (ord($payload[4]) << 40) + (ord($payload[5]) << 32) +
                (ord($payload[6]) << 24) +(ord($payload[7]) << 16) +
                (ord($payload[8]) << 8) + ord($payload[9]);
        }else{     
            $payload_len = 6;
            $masks = substr($payload, 2, 4);
            $data = substr($payload, 6);
            $len = $length;
        }
        $text = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i) {    
            $text .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i%4];
        }
        $decMessages[] = $text;

        $payload = substr($payload, $payload_len+$len, strlen($payload));     
    }while (($len < strlen($data)) and $countert < 10);
        return $decMessages;
}

function encode($message){
    $length = strlen($message);
    $bytesHeader = [];
    $bytesHeader[0] = 129; // 0x1 text frame (FIN + opcode)

    if ($length <= 125) {
        $bytesHeader[1] = $length;
    }else if($length >= 126 && $length <= 65535) {
        $bytesHeader[1] = 126;
        $bytesHeader[2] = ( $length >> 8 ) & 255;
        $bytesHeader[3] = ( $length      ) & 255;
    }else{
        $bytesHeader[1] = 127;
        $bytesHeader[2] = ( $length >> 56 ) & 255;
        $bytesHeader[3] = ( $length >> 48 ) & 255;
        $bytesHeader[4] = ( $length >> 40 ) & 255;
        $bytesHeader[5] = ( $length >> 32 ) & 255;
        $bytesHeader[6] = ( $length >> 24 ) & 255;
        $bytesHeader[7] = ( $length >> 16 ) & 255;
        $bytesHeader[8] = ( $length >>  8 ) & 255;
        $bytesHeader[9] = ( $length       ) & 255;
    }

    $str = implode(array_map("chr", $bytesHeader)) . $message;
    return $str;
}
```